# Cannot convert from float to int Processing/Java

Tags: processing

I have some code here:

```java
int mutate(float x){
   if (random(1) < .1){
   float offset = randomGaussian()/2;
   float newx = x + offset;
   return newx;
 } else {
    return x; 
 }
}
```

This code gives an error on both samples of returning a value saying "Type mismatch: Cannot convert from float to int."  What is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should get into the habit of researching your problem. Googling your error message would have given you a ton of results explaining what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the return type to float in order to return decimal values (if that's what you are interested in):

```
float mutate(float x){
    if (random(1) < .1){
        float offset = randomGaussian()/2;
        float newx = x + offset;
        return newx;
    } else {
        return x; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, remember what `int` and `float` are:

- `int` can only hold whole numbers without decimal places, like `1`, `42`, and `-54321`.
- `float` can hold numbers with decimal places, like `0.25`, `1.9999`, and `-543.21`.

So, you need to figure out what you meant to return from your function: should it be an `int` or a `float` value? If it's supposed to be a `float` value, then you can simply change the return type of the function to `float`. If you want it to return an `int` value, then you'll have to rethink the logic inside your function so it's using `int` values instead.

Note that you can convert from a `float` to an `int` using the `int()` function. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/intconvert_.html).